# Indexing by multiple fields with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am new to Pandas. I have the following data (stock prices)

```
id,date,time,price
0,2015-01-01,9:00,21.72
1,2015-01-01,9:00,17.65
2,2015-01-01,9:00,54.24
0,2015-01-01,11:00,21.82
1,2015-01-01,11:00,18.65
2,2015-01-01,11:00,52.24
0,2015-01-02,9:00,21.02
1,2015-01-02,9:00,19.01
2,2015-01-02,9:00,50.21
0,2015-01-02,11:00,20.61
1,2015-01-02,11:00,18.70
2,2015-01-02,11:00,51.21
...
...
```

I want to sort by date and calculate returns for each id and across dates and times within a date. I tried this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/csv", index_col=[0,2,1])
df['returns'] = df['price'].pct_change()
```

However, the returns are calculated across the ids in the order they appear. Any idea how to do this correctly? I would also like to access the data as

```
price_0 = df['id'==0]['date'=='2014-01-01'][time=='9:00']['price']
```

Comment: You should indicate what you are expecting as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that those are the columns in your dataframe (and none are the index), then you want to group by date, time, and id on price.  You then unstack the id, which effectively creates a pivot table with dates and times as the rows and ids as the columns.  You then need to use `pct_change` to achieve your objective.

```
returns = df.groupby(['date', 'time', 'id']).price.first().unstack().pct_change()

>>> returns
id                   0         1         2
date   time                               
1/1/15 11:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
       9:00  -0.004583 -0.053619  0.038285
1/2/15 11:00 -0.051105  0.059490 -0.055863
       9:00   0.019893  0.016578 -0.019527
```

It will probably be better, however, to combine the dates and times into timestamps.  Assuming your dates and times are text representations, the following should work:

```
df['timestamp'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Timestamp(row.date + ' ' + row.time), axis=1)
```

Then, just group on the the timestamp and id, and unstack the id.

```
returns = df.groupby(['timestamp, 'id']).price.first().unstack('id').pct_change()

>>> returns
id                          0         1         2
timestamp                                        
2015-01-01 09:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
2015-01-01 11:00:00  0.004604  0.056657 -0.036873
2015-01-02 09:00:00 -0.036664  0.019303 -0.038859
```

You would index the returns for a given security as follows:

```
>>> returns.ix['2015-01-02 9:00'].loc[1]
0.0193029490616623
```

Comment: Thanks. In the first case (where date and time are not combined), how do I access individual id and returns returns.ix['2015-01-02']['9:00'] doesn't work or some of the combinations I tried.